# How to write down existence and uniqueness?

Tags: syntax, logic

Mathematica has strong commands `ForAll`and `Exists`. However, I face difficulties, trying to express "existence and uniqueness" in Mathematica 11.2.0.0. Here is an example.

```
ForAll[y, y > 0, Exists[x, x \[Element] Reals, Exp[x] == y]] && 
  ForAll[y1, y1 > 0,  ForAll[x1, x1 \[Element] Reals, ForAll[x2, x2 \[Element] Reals,  
Implies[Exp[x1] == y1 && Exp[x2] == y1, x1 == x2]]]]
```

> $$\forall _{y,y>0}\exists _{x,x\in \mathbb{R}}e^x=y\land \forall _{\text{y1},\text{y1}>0}\forall _{\text{x1},\text{x1}\in \mathbb{R}}\forall _{\text{x2},\text{x2}\in \mathbb{R}}\left(e^{\text{x1}}=\text{y1}\land e^{\text{x2}}=\text{y1}\Rightarrow \text{x1}=\text{x2}\right) $$

```
Resolve[%, {x, y, x1, x2, y1}, Reals]
```

> $$\forall _{\{y\},y>0}\exists _{\{x\},x\in \mathbb{R}}e^x=y\land \forall _{\{\text{y1}\},\text{y1}>0}\forall _{\{\text{x1}\},\text{x1}\in \mathbb{R}}\forall _{\{\text{x2}\},\text{x2}\in \mathbb{R}}\left(e^{\text{x1}}=\text{y1}\land e^{\text{x2}}=\text{y1}\Rightarrow \text{x1}=\text{x2}\right) $$

instead of expected `True`. Is it possible to implement the above in Mathematica?